# A Void in my Heart

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, poetry

> Exit the games, log off the Internet,
>   Avert the kids vocalizing with the tv set,
>   Silence the ringtones and with quiet song
>   Bring out my friend, let his subjects say so long.
>
> For eleven years he let me share his home,
>   This King of Beasts who in this place did roam.
>   Majestic, lazy, IQ of a gnat:
>   His Excellency, my "Magnificat".
>
> I called this friend a gentle giant, because
>   Slow to anger, quick to eat he was:
>   With joyously exuberant zeal he'd greet
>   Each plate of food he'd been given to eat.
>
> Big in body, big in love, this friend.
>   With zest for life he purred, up to the end,
>   But noxious tumors took his voice from me.
>   He lives now just in this soliloquy.

To whom did I say farewell tonight?

Comment: Aw man, now I'm gonna cry T^T

Comment: Maybe worth noting: As well as the work mentioned in Deusovi's answer, Rubio's poem is a bit of an homage to this rather beautiful one by W H Auden: https://allpoetry.com/Funeral-Blues.

Comment: This is essentially exactly the same puzzle as [this older one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/18509/5373), just with a different solution. *must ... resist ... urge ... to ... use ... dupehammer ...*

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You said farewell to:

> PUMA, which I assume is the name of your cat. The first stanza has all letters but P, the second is missing U, the third is missing M, and the fourth is missing A. (This is clued by "A Void" in the title, the name of a book by Georges Perec that's intentionally missing the letter E.)

Comment: "Slow to anger, quick to eat he was" could be a dog, though you definitely have the right answer.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL The word Magnificat is in inverted commas.

Comment: @NikhilBhavar Ah, missed that.

Comment: So it's a lipogram?

Comment: Dogs aren't often described as purring, either ...

Comment: Or La Disparation, to assign it its original affirmation.